Transfer data from one database to another using IDs in kafka topic
I store some non-incremental IDs in a topic.
Next, I need to make a query from one database using these IDs, transform data and put result in another database.
Can this be implemented using kafka/kafka-connect? If so, how?
I think, this can be done using kafka-connect JdbcSourceConnector, but I don’t know how to write the config.
